# In fullcalendar how to forbid select in my custom view

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-2

I'm using fullcalendar. I have a custom view, but I don't want users to be able to select a time range on this view.

```
            selectable: true,
            defaultView: 'multiColAgendaDay',
            events: '/events.json',
            views: {
                multiColAgendaDay:
                {
                    type: 'multiColAgenda',
                    duration: { days: 1 },
                    numColumns: gon.driver_num,
                    columnHeaders: gon.drivers_name,
                    buttonText: 'drivers'
                    // ,
                }
            },
```

I tried to solve this by adding a check in select

```
            select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
                if (view.name === 'multiColAgendaDay'){
                    calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
                    alert("You can create event in week and day view.");
                    return;
                }
                $.getScript('/events/new', function () {
                    $('#event_date_range').val(moment(start).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm") + ' - ' + moment(end).format("MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm"))
                    date_range_picker();
                    $('.start_hidden').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
                    $('.end_hidden').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
                });

                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            },
```

I would like to know other approaches. I hope there is a way to set selectable to false in a specific view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `selectable: false` to your view definition (the same way you add other properties to it). e.g.

```
multiColAgendaDay:
{
  type: 'multiColAgenda',
  duration: { days: 1 },
  numColumns: gon.driver_num,
  columnHeaders: gon.drivers_name,
  buttonText: 'drivers',
  selectable: false
}
```

When you're using this view, this overrides the top-level setting for `selectable`. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/view-specific-options#v2 for documentation.

As long as you're using fullCalendar 2.4 or above, this should work.